# Possible hdd problem

Tags: boot, hard-drive

Yesterday afternoon, I dropped my laptop on the floor, I went to turn it on and I noticed that my Ubuntu won't boot. I went through the boot selection of the BIOS itself and I realize that my HD does not appear. Even being connected perfectly. However, when I put my pendrive with Ubuntu installed, I can run the pre-installation perfectly, but I can't install it because the Distro only detects my pendrive as a storage medium to install. I must conclude that the problem is in the HD that is dead, right?

Comment: To be 100 percent sure you would need to take it for repair. Yes I would guess you killed the hard drive.

Comment: BTW Why ask here this is a Ubuntu OS support site.

Comment: Next time, install SSD. It will work even you drop your laptop, (don't drop).